# Hyper-V machines not recognised after Windows 10 Upgrade (xml vs. vmcx)

Tags: hyper-v

I'm in the process of updating an older Windows 10 1511 box with several VM on it.

After Windows Update has updated to 1709 (why not directly to 21H1?) all VMs but one are gone.
All of them are still in xml format and not in the newer vmcx format.

If i try to import the VMs, the VM is listed in the import dialog but when importing it I get a 'Unspecified error'.

How do I import or convert the existing old VMs (xml)?

Comment: Try this Microsoft Article .... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4b26c014-13de-454e-b515-f01b72692ac8/how-to-import-hyperv-s2008r2-exported-vms-in-hyperv-s2012r2?forum=winserverhyperv

Comment: “After Windows Update has updated to 1709 (why not directly to 21H1?” - Processor requirements changed when 1709 without knowing what hardware you had I suspect your hardware is incompatible with any version newer than 1709.  As for the VMs, you have practically told us nothing about them, an upgrade to 1709 wouldn’t have touched your personal files

Comment: VMs are all Gen1 with various OS. Some (or most) where created when the Box had Win8 running, that was later updated to Win10. CPU is Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1240 v2. (v5 is listed on all Win10 versions, v2 is not listed on 1511 or 1709)

Answer (score 0):

Because I needed a solution fast, the only way I could come up was to restore the system from an image backup to 1511 and convert the VMs to config version 7.0 prior to let Windows Update installing 1709.

PS: A few boot cycles later, Windows Update installed 20H2. Therefore works with Xeon E3-1240 v2.